# Wordpress does not display content

Tags: php, wordpress

Picked up the code from other theme i've been training on, where it was working perfectly fine. However, here, i can't get it to display content. No trace of posts on index page at all. And on other pages, it only shows page titles.
website here: 
soloveich.com

index page content code

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="body">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2"></div>
<div class="span8" id="conty">
<div id="title"><h4>Your Company Name</h4></div>
<div id="content">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span2"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

other pages code

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="body">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2"></div>
<div class="span8" id="conty">
<div id="title"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div>
<div id="content">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show up the full code for one of these pages?  What does the 'entry' template contain?  Is your second code block within the loop?

Comment: edited the first post

Comment: What's in the header file?  And the entry file?